# Where does cucumber look for cucumber.xml?

Tags: spring, cucumber-jvm

I have a folder layout like this:

```
src/integrationTest/java/
  com/eric/
    RunCukeTest.java
    StepDefs.java
src/integrationTest/resources/
  features/
    foo.feature
  cucumber.xml
src/main/java/
  com/eric/
    java-spring.java
src/main/resources/
  com/eric/
    applicationContext.xml
```

I have cucumber spring 1.1.5 on my classpath

I cannot get RunCukeTest.java to pick up cucumber.xml when I run as a JUnit test in eclipse. How does cucumber resolve where cucumber.xml is supposed to live?

Thanks!
Eric

Answer (score 2):

It should be in the root of resources directory. In your case it should be src/integrationTest/resources

Answer (score 1):

[One of the commits](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/commit/513090e60ea0d2792867c55cdc341b2d233c63f7) introduced by v1.1.4 made a major change in the `SpringFactory` class where "cucumber.xml" was removed from the list of application context files to be loaded (still trying to figure out why).

To fix this you have to use `@ContextConfiguration({"cucumber.xml"})` **in the step definition classes**.

*src/test/java/example/cucumber/Runner.java*

```java
@RunWith(Cucumber.java)
public class Runner {
    // nothing here
}
```

*src/test/java/example/cucumber/RunnerStepDefs.java*

```java
@ContextConfiguration({ "cucumber.xml" })
public class RunnerStepDefs {

    @Autowired
    private SuperBean super;

    // moar stuff
}
```

Tested with Spring 3.0.6 and Cucumber-JVM 1.1.5.

Answer (score 0):

In cucumber 1.1.5 cucumber.xml is not read. Until 1.1.3 the SpringFactory class in cucumber-spring jar used to load beans defined in cucumber.xml using applicationContext defined in static block of SpringFactory class.